# what is copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true)

Tags: android, copy, bitmapfactory

In this code:

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image1).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
```

What does `copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true)` do?

Comment: Here you go - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#copy(android.graphics.Bitmap.Config,%20boolean)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`BitmapFactory.decodeResource`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeResource%28android.content.res.Resources,%20int,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options%29) returns a [`Bitmap`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html), [`Bitmap.copy`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#copy%28android.graphics.Bitmap.Config,%20boolean%29) creates a mutable copy of the image using the option specified.

[`BitMap.Config.ARGB_8888`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html):

> Each pixel is stored on 4 bytes.